# Is this normal socket behavior?

Tags: c, sockets

I have a small c program which continually accepts data from one server and then translates it and sends it to a second server.  The second server (basically a terminal app) then sends back the command prompt characters.  When I send data to the second server it works as expected. If I do not read the data returned from the second server, then the second time I send data it never receives the data even though my program sends it and does not generate any errors.  If I read the data returned by the second server it works as expected.

Can anyone explain this behavior?  I am just curious as to what is going on.  Both my process and the remote processes are continually running.

```
int sendCCL_TCP(unsigned char *buf, struct sockaddr_in *ccladdr){
    
    int n,outfd;
    if ((outfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0) {
        fprintf(errorfd,"ERROR creating output socket to send CCL\n");
        fclose(errorfd);
        return(FALSE);
    }    

    if (connect(outfd, (struct sockaddr *)ccladdr, sizeof(*ccladdr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(errorfd,"ERROR connecting to CCL server (%i) %s \n",errno,strerror(errno));
        fflush(errorfd);
    }
    else{       
        n = write(outfd, buf, strlen(buf));
        if (n < 0) {
            fprintf(errorfd,"ERROR writing to CCL server (%i) %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
            fflush(errorfd);
        }
        write(outfd,"\r",1);            

        //If I comment out the following, the remote server does not 
        //receive the data the second and subsequent times
        n=read(outfd,buf,9);
    }
    close(outfd);   
    return(TRUE);   
}
```

Comment: We probably need to see the other side as well.

Comment: Please show the code for the 'second server'.  If it uses blocking writes on a socket then failure to read the other end may result in a deadlock of sorts with both ends waiting for the other to read previously written data.

Comment: For the purpose of testing I use a program called "Port Listener" which shows connect, data and disconnect.  I do not have the source but if I connect to it with netcat it immediately sends "Hello" back.  The actual "other side" is netburner's virtual com port driver which is connected to a legacy serial dumb terminal program.

Comment: We need to see the first server code...

Comment: There are 3 servers src, translator, dest.  my code runs on the translator server and the src  server is the tcp "client" to the translators tcp "server".  That connection works perfectly.  when the translator server sends to the dest. server is where the issue occurs and is what the code shown is for.

Comment: In any case: check the return values from `read()` and `write()`. **dont** assume they return the same value as their 3rd argument.

Comment: If you don't read what is sent to you, the sender will ultimately stall, and if you close a socket with unread data it will issue a 'connection reset' to the peer. Moral: read the data.